# MKMapView automatically zoom in to current location when I zoom out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've created `MKMapView` and used `UIBarButtonItem` for `zoom out` to show all `regions`. It worked fine on iPhone Simulator but when I try on device it was `zoom` back to `current location` after 3-5 seconds or sometimes 10. I don't know what something wrong here. Thanks for any advice.

This following is my code

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapListViewController.h"

@class MCLocation;

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MapListViewControllerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    NSArray *locations;

    __weak IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
    __weak IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mapTypeControl;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCLocation *item;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (IBAction)changeMapType:(id)sender;
- (void)zoomLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)i;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MCLocation.h"
#import "MCLocationStore.h"
#import "MapDetailViewController.h"


#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize item;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Map"];

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
        [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

        UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"User.png"];
        UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:userImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showUser)];

        UIImage *locationImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:locationImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showLocation)];

        [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItems:leftButton];
        [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:rightButton];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return [self init];
}

- (MKCoordinateRegion)regionForAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations
{
MKCoordinateRegion region;

if ([annotations count] == 0) {
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(worldView.userLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);

} else if ([annotations count] == 1) {
    id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [annotations lastObject];
    region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);

} else {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations)
    {
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    }

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 2.0;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.5;

    region.span = span;
    region.center = worldView.userLocation.coordinate;

return [worldView regionThatFits:region];
}

- (IBAction)showUser 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(worldView.userLocation.coordinate, 250, 250);
    [worldView setRegion:[worldView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)showLocation 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [self regionForAnnotations:locations];
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (void)updateLocations 
{
    if (locations != nil) {
        [worldView removeAnnotations:locations];
    }

    locations = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
    [worldView addAnnotations:locations];
}

- (void)zoomLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)i 
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation = i;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [worldView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

    [worldView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}

- (void)performFetch 
{
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        FATAL_CORE_DATA_ERROR(error);
        return;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [worldView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    [self performFetch];
    [self loadMapTypePref];
    [self updateLocations];

    // If we have locations, then show them on the map. If there are no
// locations, then let the map view figure out how to center on the
// user's position. It will usually do a pretty good job.
    if ([locations count] > 0) {
        [self showLocation];
    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [mapTypeControl setHidden:YES];

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [item coordinate];
        [worldView setCenterCoordinate:coord animated:NO];
        [self zoomLocation:coord];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    worldView = nil;
    mapTypeControl = nil;
    locations = nil;
    fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [locationManager setDelegate:nil];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation 
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{   
    static NSString *LocationIdentifier = @"Location";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[worldView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:LocationIdentifier];

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MCLocation class]]) {
        if (!annotationView) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:LocationIdentifier];
        } 
        [annotationView setAnnotation:annotation];
        [annotationView setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed];
        [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
        [annotationView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
        [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];
        [annotationView setCalloutOffset:CGPointMake(-5, 5)];
        [annotationView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        UIButton *rightButton = nil;
        UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkcup-map-pin.png.png"];
        UIImageView *leftButton = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];

        rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

        [annotationView setRightCalloutAccessoryView:rightButton];
        [annotationView setLeftCalloutAccessoryView:leftButton];

        return annotationView;
    } else {
        [[worldView userLocation] setTitle:@"You're here"];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control 
{
    // Call out code
}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    NSTimeInterval t = [[newLocation timestamp] timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (t < -180) {
        return;
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    //
}


#pragma mark - Fetched results controller

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{
    if (fetchedResultsController) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create and configure a fetch request with the Book entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    MCLocationStore *ls = [MCLocationStore sharedStore];
    self.managedObjectContext = ls.context;

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MCLocation" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create the sort descriptors array.
    NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"storeName" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sd, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"MapView"];

    return fetchedResultsController;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

You've implemented the map view's `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method and in there you are zooming the map to the user's location.

That delegate method will get called whenever the device gets a location update.

So after you zoom or pan away, if there's another location update, the delegate method gets called and it zooms back to the user location.

One option is to keep a boolean ivar (say `didZoomToUserLocation`) and in that method, you should only zoom (ie. call `setRegion`) if the flag is `NO`.  Set the flag to `YES` in that method after calling `setRegion`.

In iOS 5 and up, you could also try [setting the `userTrackingMode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW62) to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` instead of manually zooming.  I think that mode gives the user some freedom to pan around while still following the user.